# How can I get the IP of the docker host on a Linux system from a docker container?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

This question appears to have been asked many times, but the answers appear to be outdated, or just not work.

I'm on a Linux system without a RTC (a raspberry pi). My host runs an ntp daemon (`ntpd`), which checks the time online as soon as the host boots up, assuming it has internet, and sets the system clock.

The code inside my container needs to know if the host's system clock is accurate (has been updated since last boot).

On the host itself, this is very easy to do - use something like `ntpdate -q 127.0.0.1`. `ntpdate` connects to `127.0.0.1:123` over udp, and checks with the `ntpd` daemon if the clock is accurate (if it's been updated since last boot). This appears to be more difficult to do from within a container.

If I start up a container, and use `docker container inspect NAME` to see the container's IP, it shows me this:

```
"Gateway": "172.19.0.1",
"IPAddress": "172.19.0.6",
```

If I run `ntpdate -q 172.19.0.1` within the container, this works. Unfortunately, `172.19.0.1` isn't a permanent IP for the host. It that subnet is already taken when the container is starting up, the subnet will change, so hardcoding this IP is a bad idea. What I need is an environment variable that always reflects the proper IP for the host.

Windows and MacOS versions of docker appear to set the `host.docker.internal` hostname within containers, but Linux doesn't. Some people recommend setting this in the `/etc/hosts` file of the host, but then you're just hardcoding the IP, which again, can change.

I run my docker container with a `docker-compose.yml` file, and apparently, on new versions of docker, you can do this:

```
extra_hosts:
    - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

I tried this, and this works. Sort of. Inside my container, `host.docker.internal` resolves to `172.17.0.1`, which is IP of the `docker0` interface on the host. While I can ping `host.docker.internal` from within the container, using `ntpdate -q host.docker.internal` or `ntpdate -q 172.17.0.1` doesn't work.

Is there a way to make `host.docker.internal` resolve to the proper gateway IP of the host from within the container? In my example, `172.19.0.1`.

Note: Yes, I can use code within the container to check what the container's gateway is with `netstat` or similar, but then I need to complicate my code, making it figure out the IP of the NTP server (the docker host). I can probably also pass the docker socket into the container, and try to get the docker host's IP through that, but that seems super hackey, and an unnecessary security issue.

Comment: Containers aren't a VM, the time inside the container should be the same as their host. Why not run this command (or a daemon) on the host?

Comment: @BMitch Exactly. Which means if the host's time is accurate, so is the container's time. That's literally the reason I'm trying to check with the host if it's time is accurate. `Why not run this command on the host` - see reason for Docker's existence.

Comment: Docker doesn't isolate the kernel, there's only one time on the host and container because time itself isn't namespaced. So access to change the time is blocked by default since it would apply to the host and every other container. That's why this seems like something you should be doing outside of a container.

Comment: @BMitch I didn't say I want to change the time. I said I want to check if the time is accurate. Read only operation. Relative to real-world time. Either the host has used ntp to update time since it booted, or it hasn't. Yes, the time inside and outside of the container is the same, but only `ntpd` knows if it's updated the time since last boot, and `ntpd` runs outside of the container, so there's no way to get this info from within the container without talking to the host's `ntpd` service

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've found is to use the `ip` command from the `iproute2` package, look for the default route and use the gateway address for it.

```
ip route | awk '/default/ {print $3}'
```

if you want it in an environment variable, you can set it in an entrypoint script with

```
export HOST_IP_ADDRESS=$(ip route | awk '/default/ {print $3}')
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's literally the same approach as the `netstat` approach I mentioned - just different syntax. I was hoping for docker to tell me, instead of writing code to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

> While I can ping `host.docker.internal` from within the container, using `ntpdate -q host.docker.internal` or `ntpdate -q 172.17.0.1` doesn't work.

The most likely reason for this is that your NTP server on the host doesn't bind to the docker interface. In fact chances are that the docker interface doesn't even exist when your NTP server starts up.

You can confirm this by running a simple webserver on the host:

```bash
python -m http.server
```

Then trying to access it from the container:

```bash
curl http://host.docker.internal:8000
```

If this works, it confirms that you can access the host from within the container.

As for the NTP server, try restarting it once docker networks are set up and see if it helps it bind to the docker interface.